# Point of intersection between two bodies

Tags: computer-vision, detection

[image: Figure illustrating task I want to accomplish]

I am working on a project where I draw a line on an image that is coming from lets say a webcam and shows different object. I draw on these objects my desired line (shown in red). Now I want to find the spot (coordinates) where my line intersect a body ( green box in the figure). Any help of suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: What language? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am using C++. I intend to use opencv. I dont have a strong background in vision relate stuff so any hints or papers would be helpful